# My Gmail email to a Google group gets there, but I don't get a copy in Mail.app

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, apple-mail, google-groups, gmail-imap

I have my Gmail account set up as IMAP and use Mac Mail on 10.6.

When I post as a member to a Google group using my gmail address, I do not get my copy back from the google group in Mac Mail. I do see everyone else's posts to the group including ones where people respond to my posting.

I know the email I sent arrives at the google group by looking at my gmail account via the web where I see the copy I get back from google groups to my gmail account.

Does any one have any idea? Anyone else have this problem?

I tend to get the feeling that this is a bug in gmail/google groups.

Comment: Isn't your copy in Gmail's Sent Items (rather than the Inbox)?

Comment: To whoever voted to migrate this question to WebApps: the question is about using web services in conjunction with Mail.App, which is regular computer software. Therefore, I would say that it is a valid, on-topic question for SuperUser and should remain.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the way it works is that Google Groups receives the email, and is smart enough to know that since *you sent* the email, you don't need another copy sent back to you. In some cases a group might be configured to send you a copy of emails you submitted, which would show up in your Gmail online interface. However, since you *sent* the email, it won't download to your inbox. Gmail does not download emails to your mail client which you have sent to yourself, unless you have it set to download *all mail* from the past x days. This should apply to any email sent to your email from your own email; try it by composing an email to yourself and seeing if that works.